# docker nginx openmediavault

Tags: docker, nginx

a beginner question.

basically my Docker container is running. Nginx itself is not a problem.
But how next? Unfortunately, I do not know where to put my folders, for example Wordpress installation, so I can access them via NGinx.

I did not select an extra folder to install Nginx. Instructions do not exactly describe the problem.

Maybe someone has a very quick fix on this topic? <3

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile?

Comment: Hi 

i used https://hub.docker.com/r/nginx/unit/ within openmediavault plugin

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/xytis/docker-unit